# How to interpret the model once a set of coefficient is obtained for Multivariable polynomial regression?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I was solving a Multivariable polynomial regression problem,as a part of an online course, where one must obtain a model (polynomial form) for determining 'price of a car' as a function of 'horsepower','curb-weight','engine-size','highway-mpg'. The code given in the course slide didn't work for me and hence I tried to solve the problem on my own using a little different approach and (not sure) I succedded.

Now I want to determine which coefficient belongs to which variable and to what power.

```
   from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
   from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

   lm=LinearRegression()
   pr=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)

   zi=df[['horsepower','curb-weight','engine-size','highway-mpg']]
   y=df["price"]

   x_poly=pr.fit_transform(zi)
   lm.fit(x_poly,y)
   y_poly_pred=lm.predict(x_poly)

   print(lm.intercept_)

   print(lm.coef_)
```

The output of the 'print(lm.coef_)' is an array:

```
[  3.76158683e+02,   1.09866844e+01,  -1.15342835e+02,   2.20081486e+02,
   1.67487147e+00,  -1.85925420e-01,  -1.27963440e+00,  -1.97616945e+00,
   5.93872420e-04,   1.11397083e-01,  -2.12935236e-01,   1.04605018e-01,
   2.69312438e-01,   4.36657298e+00]
```

How can I assign or know to which variables and to which powers each of these coeffecients correspond to?

Comment: @Sarthank - did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing is, You can get the ploymomialfeature column names like this

```
pr.get_feature_names(zi.columns)
```

and

```
pd.DataFrame(zip(pr.get_feature_names(zi.columns),lm.coef_),columns=["feature","coef_"])
```

Above should print the coef for each feature

Working example :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'x': np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=5),
    'y': np.random.randint(low=-1, high=1, size=5),
})

lm=LinearRegression()
p = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

p_data = p.fit_transform(data)

lm.fit(p_data,data['y'])

print (p.get_feature_names(data.columns))

coefmapping = pd.DataFrame(zip(p.get_feature_names(data.columns),lm.coef_),columns=["feature","coef_"])

print(coefmapping)
```

output:

```
  feature         coef_
0       1 -1.204939e-14
1       x -1.165951e-15
2       y  5.000000e-01
3     x^2 -6.938894e-18
4     x y -3.156113e-16
5     y^2 -5.000000e-01
```

Comment: Thanks.. the first line of code i.e.'pr.get_feature_names(zi.columns)' worked pretty well. I obtained a list of features for which I wasa concerned. 
However, I am getting an error for the second line of code 
i.e. 'pd.DataFrame(zip(pr.get_feature_names(zi.columns),lm.coef_),columns=["feature","coef_"])' . _TypeError_: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: @SarthakHajirnis - Still you are facing the issue. Or you resolved it

Comment: I am getting an error for the code  'pd.DataFrame(zip(pr.get_feature_names(zi.columns),lm.coef_),columns=["feature","coef_"])' . 
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: Can you try this :  feature_name = pr.get_feature_names(zi.columns),  pd.DataFrame(zip(feature_name ,lm.coef_),columns=["feature","coef_"])

Comment: No man, it didn't work out either. However I used another approach

'data={'feature':feature_name,'coef_':lm.coef_}
ddf = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(ddf)'

This yielded the desired result.
Again Thank you so much for the help..!